# Adsense tokens "[adsense:XxY:SlotID]" in node content aren't being replaced by ads

Tags: javascript, input-formats, tokens

I've added adsense tags in my node body/content and I'm using Full HTML as text format.

For this Full HTML ipnut format I've enabled "replace adsense tags".
I've also given it the highest "Priority" so that it is done before anything else related to formatting node content.

In the end, adsense tokens are printed as is "[adsense:XxY:SlotID]" and no ads. From developer console I can see one error that states:

```
TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: All ins elements in the DOM with class=adsbygoogle already have ads in them.
```

I'm quite sure that if these tokens were replaced by ad markup that error wouldn't show up in the developer console.

And to be honest, I'm not sure which modules is responisble for formatting adsense tokens into adsense markup i.e. which modules provides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, finally solved. Since pages are rendered via Panels the solution was to check "Clean" option from Panel content manager to the node body which removes "dangerous" markup.

In other words it seems like node body doesn't respect text format settings when rendered via Panels. Or at least not all of it without checking this option.